# I need some help accessing a member function in a protected array in PHP

Tags: php, oop, function

Right now I'm trying to write a function that would allow me to access member functions. The code in question looks a little like this:

```
protected $formName;
protected $formClass;
protected $formAction;
protected $formMethod;
protected $formObjArray = array(); //outputs in order. So far it should only take newLine, selectTag, inputTag, textTag.
protected $submitBtnVal;
protected $encType;

function __construct($args) {
  $this->formName = $args['formName'];
  $this->formAction = $args['formAction'];

  if (isset($args['formClass'])) $this->formClass = $args['formClass'];
  if (isset($args['encType'])) $this->encType = $args['encType'];

  //default should be POST. Hell, you should never really be using GET for this..
  //also, the default submit value is Submit
  $this->formMethod = isset($args['formMethod']) ? $args['formMethod'] : "POST"; 
  $this->submitBtnVal = isset($args['submitBtnVal']) ? $args['submitBtnVal'] : "Submit";
}

//get functions
function getFormName () { return $this->formName; }
function getFormAction () { return $this->formAction; }
function getFormMethod () { return $this->formMethod; }
function getSubmitBtnVal () { return $this->submitBtnVal; }
function getEncType () { return $this->encType; }

//set functions
function setFormName ($newName) { $this->fromName = $newName; }
function setFormAction ($newAction) { $this->formAction = $newAction; }
function setFormMethod ($newMethod) { $this->formMethod = $newMethod; }
function setEncType ($newEType) { $this->encType = $newEType; }

function addTag($newTag) {
  if ($newTag instanceof formTag || $newTag instanceof fieldSetCont || $newTag instanceof newLine
      || $newTag instanceof noteTag)
    $this->formObjArray[] = $newTag;
  else throw new Exception ("You did not add a compatible tag.");
}
```

I'd like to be able to call `$myForm->getTagByName("nameA")->setRequired(true);`

How would I do that? Or would I need to do something more like..

```
$tagID = $myForm->getTagByName("nameA");
$myForm->tagArray(tagID)->setRequired(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in your code seems to be protected so you should have no trouble accessing any of it.

It looks like all your tags are in $formObjArray so it should be trivial to filter than array and return tags that match the name you've passed in. The trouble you will have is that, `getTagByName` really should be `getTagsByName` and should return an array because you can have more than one tag with the same name. Since it will return an array, you can not call `setRequired` on the return value, arrays don't have such a method. You'll need to do it more like:

```
$tags = $myForm->getTagsByName("nameA");
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $tag->setRequired(true);
}
```

Exactly what are you stuck on? Maybe I don't understand the question very well.

So maybe the filtering has you stuck? Try this (if you you're using at least php 5.3)

```
function getTagsByName($tagname) 
{
    return array_filter($this->formObjArray, function($tag) use($tagname) { 
        return $tag->getName() == $tagname; 
    });
}
```

No ifs or switches.

Prior to 5.3, you don't have lambda functions so you need to do it differently. There are several options but this may be the simplest to understand:

```
function getTagsByName($tagname) 
{
    $out = array();
    foreach ($this->formObjArray as &$tag) {
        if ($tag->getName() == $tagname) {
            $out[] = $tag;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for a more generic way of doing that rather than having to pass the tag and name (because that's a lot of if-switches in try  blocks.)

Comment: If you're using php 5.3 or up, you can do it about 1 line of code. For older versions, it's only slightly more complicated. But you certainly don't need a lot of ifs.

Comment: I got the commit to work properly, the entire code block is here [link]https://github.com/KoihimeNakamura/SC-Assistant/blob/master/inc/class_newForm.php

Comment: Hn. Well, I just checked the environments. My local one is 5.3 but the production appears to be 5.2

Comment: OK, a minor change was needed since the name of the tag needs to be accessed by 'getName()' but basically this should work for you.

Comment: Ah, for php less than 5.3 you don't have lambda functions so you need to do it a different way. But not very different.

Comment: And after some thought, this one is probably the better of the two, since it keeps in mind my form perfectly allows multiple tags with the same names.

Comment: Happy to be of service, princess.

Answer (score 1):

In your addTag method, you are storing new tags in $this->formObjArray using the [] notation, which will just append the new tag to the end of the array. If your tag objects all have a getName() method, then you can do something like this:

```
$this->formObjArray[$newTag->getName()] = $newTag;
```

Then, you can easily add a getTagByName() method:

```
public function getTagByName($name) {
  if (array_key_exists($name, $this->formObjArray) {
    return $this->formObjArray($name);
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Please beware of the solutions suggesting you to iterate through all the tags in your array! This could become very costly as your form gets larger.

If you need to use the [] construct because the order of the elements added is important, then you can still maintain a separate index by name, $this->tagIndex, that will be an associative array of name => tag. Since you are storing object references, they will not be using much space. Assuming that getTagByName will be used many times, this will save you a lot of resources over iterating the tags array on every call to getTagByName.

In that case, your addTag method would look like this:

```
$this->formObjArray[] = $newTag;
$this->tagIndex[$newTag->getName()] = $newTag; // it seems that you're doubling the memory needed, but you're only storing object references so this is safe
```

**EDIT** : Here is some modified code to account for the fact that multiple tags can have the same name:

In your addTag() method, do:

```
$this->formObjArray[] = $newTag;
$tag_name = $newTag->getName();
if (!array_key_exists($tag_name, $this->tagIndex)) {
  $this->tagIndex[$tag_name] = array();
}
$this->tagIndex[$tag_name][] = $newTag
```

You can then rename getTagByName to getTagsByName and get the expected result.

As mentioned in the comments, this is only useful if you will call getTagsByName multiple times. You are trading a little additional memory usage in order to get quicker lookups by name.

Comment: It is. On that note, I assume that this means when I then call on it's function on the call (not in the form itself) that it'll pass it to the reference returned?

Comment: Yes. You will get the reference returned. Outside your form, you can do exactly what you wanted which is `$tag = $my_form->getTagByName('nameA')` or even `$my_form->getTagByName('nameA')->callMethodOnTag(parameters)`

Comment: This only works if the the name is unique (you can't rely on this, it's common to have form elements with the same name) and it's only useful if name is the only value you will ever want to search by.

Comment: Okonomiyaki3000 is correct. I have edited my solution to account for multiple tags with the same name. However, you will receive an array as the return value since there can be many tags with the same name. It's up to you to decide what you want to do with the array.

Comment: Hm. Well, I suppose that's not always true (newLine has no name element, for example, as it's simply a holder for multiple <br>, and noteTag is similarily a holder for <p> content.). However, by the same token, the wrapper functions don't allow for a tag to be returned to the call, they outright add it to the array. I'll need to think of how to handle a returned array. (Probably by leaving notes in the documentation that it MAY return an array, so you should always check what the reference is.) (Incidently, both of these answers are pretty good - I wonder if you can say both are the answer..)

Comment: You should have a look at Zend Framework. They have a Zend_Form component that does pretty much what you seem to be doing, and you can use it with a few dependencies.

Even if you don't use it, you should take a look at the way it's designed: they make the difference between elements and decorators, whereas in your system they are all called "tags". I think that may be a nuisance to you as your forms system gets more complex.

Comment: I agree. Thing is, I don't expect to need it to get more complex than it is now. (Although from looking at the Zend Framework, I'm giving some thought into just using the Zend_Form. While reinventing the wheel was decent practice in writing classes, I'll admit right now that doesn't mean I should use it.)

Comment: Regardless, that discussion is probably best done in the chat and not.. here. Thanks for your help!